# Alternative twig path for Silex controller provider

Tags: path, twig, silex

I am creating a new controller provider that I will use across several projects, and I need to have a couple of twig templates inside the directory of this controller provider for use in some of the routes of that provider. I want to avoid having to copy all the template files into the project directory for every project that is going to use this controller provider (to have it under the `twig.path` specified directory), so my question is this:

How can I render a template that is not located under the `twig.path` directory? Can I tell the twig service provider to render a specific path, like `__DIR__.'/views/some.template.twig'` in the controller provider file?

Answer (score 4):

You can access twig loader by using $app['twig.loader.filesystem'].

For example, put this in your controller class in connect method

```
$app['twig.loader.filesystem']->addPath(
    $pathToTemplates
);
```

There are also exists Twig_Loader_Filesystem::prependPath()

You can also specify namespace for paths. To do this just add name of namespace as second parameter, 'NAMESPACE', for instance. In that case you can access your templates by `$app['twig']->render('@NAMESPACE/pathToATemplate');` Note @-char before namespace when you render it.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
$app['twig'] = $app->share($app->extend('twig', function($twig) use ($yourNewPath) {
    $twig->addLoader(new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem($yourNewPath));
    return $twig;
}));
```